# listFiles does not return files but just top level folder

Tags: java, file

I am trying to iterate over a folder

My files a located in

```
D:\PROJECT_FOLDER\rootProject\semiRootProject\project\build\resources\main\com\xxxx\pack\file.xlsx
```

However when I try to iterate over it in console it shows

```
11:39:06.731 [main] INFO  com.xxxx.util.KiePackageCreator - File found: D:\PROJECT_FOLDER\rootProject\semiRootProject\project\build\resources\main\com.
```

What's the problem? My search loop looks like this.

```
File fileFolder = new File(projectBuildDir + RESOURCE_SUBFOLDER);

for (File file : fileFolder.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        //if (name.endsWith(".xlsx")) {
            return true;
        //}
        //return false;
    }

})) {
    LOGGER.info("File found: {}.", file.toPath());
    if (file.isFile()) { 
        Resource fileResource = getClassPathResource(file.getName());
        String filePath = file.getPath();
        String rulePath = MAVEN_RESOURCE_PATH + filePath.substring(filePath.indexOf("com"));
        LOGGER.info("Attempt to write into: {}.", rulePath);
        kfs.write(rulePath, fileResource);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use recursion, that is what you need here

Answer (score 2):

List files lists all files and directories in the directory you specify. It does not do so recursively.

Maybe [walkFileTree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.FileVisitor)) suits you better.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the sub folders in your code. You are just iterating over the files in the directory that fileFolder is pointing to.